# Why this exception is coming ?java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments

**My code :**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        return view;
    }
```

**Exception :**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3509)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3380)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3325)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:591)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:6695)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6653)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:6641)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1398)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1347)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3003)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2881)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3265)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:122)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1149)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:810)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14471)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1984)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1738)
>                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1008)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5509)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
>                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Acti

Comment: can you add activity code? @NeerajSahu

Comment: this is my activity code :